# Issue with scheduling a task in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, scheduled-tasks, delphi-2010, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a task (upon clicking a button) in Windows 10. I can schedule a task from Windows "Task Scheduler" and by using the Command-Prompt, but I want to do it programmatically in Delphi. I have tried JCL that has a scheduler unit (component in the JVCL), but that did not work.

I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710741/15064216, but it's neither showing any error nor creating a task.

Can anyone please help me with this? I have been stuck with this for weeks now.
Here is my code:

```
uses
Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, 
System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,Vcl.StdCtrls,  ShellApi, 
StdStyleActnCtrls,System.Win.TaskbarCore, Vcl.Taskbar;

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
Button1: TButton;
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure ScheduleRunAtStartup(const ATaskName: string; const AFileName: 
string;
const AUserAccount: string);
begin
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'schtasks', PChar('/create /tn "' + ATaskName + '" ' + 
'/tr "' + AFileName + '" /sc ONSTART /ru "' + AUserAccount + '"'), nil, 
 SW_HIDE);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ScheduleRunAtStartup('TestScheduler','C:\Users\Scheduletest.exe','System');
 end;
```

Comment: Please show the actual code you are having trouble with in your own project. Not a link to someone else's code that inspired your code. We have no way to know if you broke something when incorporating that other person's code into your own.

Comment: Are you aware that [Task Scheduler has an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) for applications to use? You should not be spawning command-line processes to manipulate tasks, as that other answer does.

Comment: It's impossible to explain why you're having trouble with code we cannot see. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Yes, you should be using the api

Comment: Look if this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362452/delphi-itaskfolder-registertaskdefinition-not-working is working for you.